# How to find Bad characters in the column

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I am trying to pull 'COURSE_TITLE' column value from 'PS_TRAINING' table in PeopleSoft and writing into UTF-8 text file to get loaded into Workday system. The file is erroring out while loading because of bad characters(Ã â and many more) present in the column. I have used a procedure which will convert non-ascii value into space. But because of this procedure, the 'Course_Title' which are written in non-english language like Chinese, Korean, Spanish also replacing with spaces.

I even tried using regular expressions (``regexp_like(course_title, 'Ã)  only to find bad characters but since the table has hundreds of thousands of rows, it would be difficult to find all bad characters. Please suggest a way to solve this.

Comment: How do you define "bad character"?

Comment: If you have multibyte characters in your table - what is the database character set? - and are writing to a UTF-8 file, why do you want to replace any characters? This sounds like an XY problem, where really you need to check the character set at each layer and make sure they all match - Oracle database, PeopleSoft, any intermediate client, operating system(s), as well as the file.

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET is UTF-8 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is AL16UTF16.  When data get written in the file square boxes like characters are coming in the text which make load fail in workday side

Comment: Characters like � Æ

Comment: Well, some people use bad characters in their everyday life for writing... How do you want to process them? What will be the replacement for symbols that doesn't have any Latin analogous?

Comment: @angel - it still sounds like you are fixing the wrong problem. Assuming the data in the table is varchar2 and valid, something between the table and the file is not using UTF-8; or whatever you are using to read and process the file doesn't handle UTF-8 properly.

Comment: let me give a text example present in table : Calculating�safety stock/ 计算安全性计算安全存量  . so when i am opening sqr file to write the data into file , i used encoding =utf-8. I tried using ascii function to check if char(26) then replace it with blank but this function is also replacing chinese text into space. i am trying to find a way which replace special character � into space and also retain chinese character as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your approach, this may work.
Define what you want, and retrieve it.

````
select *
from PS_TRAINING 
where not regexp_like(course_title, '[0-9A-Za-z]')```

If you take out too much data, just add it to the regex
````